# What is the cheapest EC2 2core instance with a sustained minimum 1 gbps network speed

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I can't wrap my mind around how AWS EC2 classifies network performance. I have a t2.nano which has a good burst but then caps at 3 MiB/sec inbound. I am looking to upload a lot of files from local to EC2 to S3 and I want to find the cheapest Linux 2 core at least 2 GB RAM instance that will provide a sustained >1Gbps networking.

I don't know how to interpret the "Up to XX Gbps" or network performance "Moderate" or "High" statements.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a bit more information

- Curious why you're doing uploads to S3 via EC2 rather than direct? Are you doing some kind of processing?
- Can you go direct to S3?
- Is this a one off thing, or you need it 24/7 for some time?
- Can you afford to lose your instance at short notice, or is this important to be keep running?

Any AWS instance including the new ARM / Graviton instances will do 1Gbps of network bandwidth. You just need enough CPU / CPU credits / EBS bandwidth / EBS credits to keep the software operating without being restricted. Some older instances won't have enough EBS bandiwdth to do 1Gbps, but [even the t3.nano can do 1Gbps of EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html).

I'd start with a t3a.nano instance and work my way up - t3 is newer than your t3, and A is AMD chips which are a bit cheaper. You could use spot instances if it's a one off, you might be better off with an M instance for sustained CPU, you might be better off with an i instance or m5d if you want local storage. You could consider Graviton if your workload supports it.

In summary, I think in this case the answer is probably "try it and see what works for you", as it depends what you're doing on the EC2 instance, primarily how much CPS and disk is needed.

Comment: Not sure if the t3.nano can do _sustained_ 1Gbps.

Comment: The docs say it can, but I suspect it wouldn't have the CPU credits to do anything complex for long. We'd really need to understand more about what this is trying to achieve to give much more help.

Comment: There is a maximum bandwidth documented in the docs, from my experience, instances have a limit how long they can sustain this. I tested it for m5'a while ago and it depended on the specific instance type how long, but it was less than 1 hour.

After that you get baseline performance

Comment: What resource ran out after the hour? M5a should have its full allocation of CPU credits, so I wonder if EBS credits ran out. Networking isn't restricted as far as I recall - AWS probably make a good portion of their profit from their egress pricing.

Comment: No visible metric. I would advice you to just give it a try yourself. The original asker of the question probably asked for this reason.